# Local parameter of a neighbourhood

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My algebraic geometry textbook says:
"Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic variety, $P$ a closed point of $X$, {$x_1$, ... , $x_n$} local parameters which generate the maximal ideal $m_P$ of $O_{X,P}$. 
There is a sufficiently small neighbourhood $U$ of $P$ that has {$x_1$, ... , $x_n$} as sections. Then we can take a smaller neighbourhood  $V \subset U$
 such that at every closed point $Q \in V$,  {$x_1-x_1(Q)$, ... , $x_n-x_n(Q)$}  generate $m_Q$ 
(here we denote $x_i(Q)$ as the image of $x_i$ in $O_{X,Q}/m_Q$).
We call {$x_1$, ... , $x_n$} local parameters of $V$".

I can't understand the last part. How can I take such $V$ ?

Comment: You get a morphism $U\to\mathbb{A}^n$ using the $x_i$s and $P\mapsto 0$. It is also etale at $P$. Now, one can show that the map is etale in a neighbourhood $V\subset U$ of $P$ and this open set will do.